# opentelemetry-cpp: Every metric data has _field "gauge" instead of "counter"

Tags: c++, open-telemetry

We used opentelemetry-cpp v1.8.1 (metrics for now) previously on a project. Everything worked fine regarding metadata present in influxdb. Metric data that came from UpDownCounter had _field tag "counter" which was according to our expectations.
Recently we witched to 1.11.0. I did not make any changes in the code, but now each metric has _field tag that shows "gauge" even if original metricInstrument is of UpDownCounter type.
Does anybody know what can be the reason of such a behavior?
Is there a possibility to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

I was trying to debug otel library locally, made it to the place where json is formed in OtlpHttpClient::createSession(...). Observing that string does not help to find a place where metricData contains something like "counter" or "gauge".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something called an Up**Down**counter, only the `gauge` type is appropriate. Compare the following definitions from the [OpenMetrics spec](https://github.com/OpenObservability/OpenMetrics/blob/main/specification/OpenMetrics.md):

> **Gauge**: Gauges MAY increase, decrease, or stay constant over time.
> **Counter**: MUST be monotonically non-decreasing over time, starting from 0. MAY reset to 0. If present, the corresponding Created time MUST also be set to the timestamp of the reset.

I think the relevant change is this line from [the 1.10 changelog](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1100-2023-07-11):

> [EXPORTER] set is_monotonic only for instrument type kCounter [#2171](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-cpp/pull/2171)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response!
So, it looks like it is something I cannot configure?
Than we will probably have to update system tests(

Comment: At least for the places where you cannot replace an UpDownCounter with a Counter, yes. You never know if a downstream metric processor makes assumptions based on the metric type.

Comment: Thanks @Botje!
I think I should now go over documentation more carefully to figure out if something else can go wrong.
There were quite many changes since 1.8 I guess.